# Location background/foreground service

Tags: android

I'm trying to write simple app to be location aware.

The thing is I wrote location requests to be received directly in activity, but that brings up the problem, because I wanna get the results even if the activity is in background. So I know that I need to have foreground service running to be able to do any processing whenever my activity is in background.

I need this service to be started from this activity (like button click) and be then visible across activities and when my app goes into background.

So my idea is as follows. 
Start the service from activity on button press. I guess this service should be sticky. And then I should bind to this service from that activity if I want to receive location data. When app goes into background I should then promote that service into foreground service so my app stays in background and Oreo restrictions don't apply.

Is my thought process fine? Or are there better ways to achieve my requirements?Like a broadcast receiver maybe.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use the https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdatesForegroundService

Comment: Thanks you very much, that was exactly what I was looking for :)